# QThreads - Why allocate memory inside a constructor rather than having a normal class member?

Tags: c++, qt, qthread

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html

```
class Controller : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    QThread workerThread;
public:
    Controller() {
        Worker *worker = new Worker;
        worker->moveToThread(&workerThread);
        connect(&workerThread, &QThread::finished, worker, &QObject::deleteLater);
        connect(this, &Controller::operate, worker, &Worker::doWork);
        connect(worker, &Worker::resultReady, this, &Controller::handleResults);
        workerThread.start();
    }
```

My way:

```
class Controller: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Worker  objWorker;
    QThread objQThread;

    Controller();
    ~Controller();

public slots:
    void receiveImage();
};
```

and

```
Controller::Controller()
{
    objWorker.moveToThread( &objQThread );

    connect( &objWorker, &Worker::imageReady, this, &Controller::receiveImage );

    objQThread.start();
}
```

Is their method better than mine in some way? Which should be preferred in which case?

Comment: Any difference in memory allocation if using `new Controller`? everything supposes to put into the heap.

Comment: why downvotes? nn

Comment: One difference might be that the worker is freed when the work is done and not when the Controller is deconstructed.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow I don't understand, Would you please explain in the answer?

Comment: In the second example you erroneously call `deleteLater` on `&objWorker` -- `objWorker` wasn't allocated on the heap.

Comment: Oh yeah. your second example also deletes the worker when the work is done but as G.M. points out you must not. Does that clear it up?

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow I have deleted the connect deleteLater  statement. Now will you write an asnwer to explain the difference?

Comment: The difference is that one can (and does) call deleteLater when the workerThread finished while the other can not. Your second case can only delete the worker when deleting the Controller. Wether that is better or worse is up for discussion.

Comment: Also note that, if the controller gets destroyed before the thread is finished, this might introduce a race condition (since the controller will delete the worker from the main thread, while the worker is busy executing a method in the worker thread). If the controller is guaranteed to *outlive* the the worker thread, then destroying the worker object while it is threadless is safe.

Comment: By "*outlives*" I don't just mean that the `QThread` object should be destroyed before the worker `QObject`, I rather mean that the actual underlying thread is finished (`quit()` and `wait()`) and its `QThread` handle is destroyed before the worker `OObject` is...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html

> From Qt 4.8 onwards, it is possible to deallocate objects that live in
>   a thread that has just ended, by connecting the finished() signal to
>   QObject::deleteLater().

This can be achieved only by making a pointer object of the Worker class and allocating memory to it.